# Sum function and POST value in PHP

Tags: php, function, post, sum

I'm trying to get the sum between a function result and a POST value.
This is my code.

```
<?php

function sum() {
    $a = 5;
    $b = 10;
    echo "Total: ".($a + $b)."&euro;";
}

sum();

?></p>

<form id="myForm" name="FinalAccept" method="post" action="sum.php"><br>
<input id="rYes" type="radio" name="payment" value="0" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
<label>Cash on delivery</label><br>
<input id="rNo" type="radio" name="payment" value="5" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
<label>Bank transfer</label><br><br>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['payment'])) {
    echo "<span>Choose payment method.</span><br>";
    echo "<span>".(sum() - $_POST['payment'])."</span>";
}

else {
    echo "<span>Choose payment method.</span>";
}

?>
```

The result is "**15€0**" when I choose cash and "**15€-5**" when I choose bank transfer.
What should I do to make it right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You get the values as string. You have to cast them to int or use bcmath: http://php.net/manual/de/ref.bc.php

EDIT: And remove the € and dont `echo` in the function, use `return`

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` returns a string "15€", I'd imagine it's a quirk of PHP that because you are concatenating the result in the `<span>` that it just appends the $_POST on to the end.

Probably the best thing to do would be to move the `&euro;` out of the sum function and just append it to the span after the calculation:

```
if(isset($_POST['payment'])) {
    echo "<span>Choose payment method.</span><br>";
    echo "<span>".(sum() - $_POST['payment'])."&euro;</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return value instead of echo in sum function and concatenate € after you get sum

```
    function sum() {
        $a = 5;
        $b = 10;
        return $a + $b);
    }

    sum();

    ?></p>

    <form id="myForm" name="FinalAccept" method="post" action="sum.php"><br>
    <input id="rYes" type="radio" name="payment" value="0" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
    <label>Cash on delivery</label><br>
    <input id="rNo" type="radio" name="payment" value="5" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
    <label>Bank transfer</label><br><br>
    </form>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['payment'])) {
        echo "<span>Choose payment method.</span><br>";
        echo "<span>".(sum() - parseFloat($_POST['payment']))."&euro;</span>";
    }

    else {
        echo "<span>Choose payment method.</span>";
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing the total in your function so this display along with you payment:

```
function sum() {
    $a = 5;
    $b = 10;
   $total = ($a + $b);
   return $total;
}
```

The euro sign has to be et in your HTML

```
echo "<span>Total: ".(sum() - $_POST['payment'])." &euro;</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sum function does not have a return value. Instead it prints the string "Total: 15€"

You should change it like this:

```php
<?php

function sum() {
    $a = 5;
    $b = 10;
    return $a + $b;
}

sum();

?></p>

<form id="myForm" name="FinalAccept" method="post" action="sum.php"><br>
<input id="rYes" type="radio" name="payment" value="0" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
<label>Cash on delivery</label><br>
<input id="rNo" type="radio" name="payment" value="5" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
<label>Bank transfer</label><br><br>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['payment'])) {
    echo "<span>Choose payment method.</span><br>";
    echo "<span>Total: ".(sum() - (int)$_POST['payment'])." &euro;</span>";
}

else {
    echo "<span>Choose payment method.</span>";
}

?>
```

As you can see now the sum function returns the actual value of the calculation and the output string is created outside of it.
Also I casted the $_POST['payment'] variable to int to prevent XSS attacks.